# C server program unable to fork

Tags: c, fork

I have a server program written in C which is supposed to accept a request and fork a child process to handle the request. Here is the relevant code:

```
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c); 
    if (client_sock < 0) {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(1);
    }else if (pid == 0){ 
        close(socket_desc); 
        /* code to handle request */
        close(client_sock);

        // exit(0);
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
    }

    close(client_sock);
```

I want to ask that when I use `exit(0)` or `kill()` in my child process, isn't that process killed ? When I run the above program, and send requests to it, after around 10000 requests, the fork call fails with the message `fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`. If I am reliably killing the forked processes, then why does the fork call fail ? Also how do I manage this without changing system limits ?

Comment: If you connect 5000 times say, and run `ps aux`, does it show 5000 server processes?

Comment: I used `ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c`. I could see the process count for the user running the server count increase as the requests come in.

Comment: The parent needs to reap the dead child processes (e.g. with `wait`/`waitpid`, possibly by installing a `SIGCHLD` handler, or just by setting the handler to `SIG_IGN`, more details [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reap_zombie_processes_using_a_sigchld_handler.html)); otherwise the child processes stick around as zombies waiting for the parent to read their exit status.

Comment: Should I still keep the `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL)` call in the child and catch that signal in the parent ? Is that correct ?

Comment: @Jake The parent needs to reap the dead child processes (e.g. with wait/waitpid, possibly by installing a SIGCHLD handler, or just by setting the handler to SIG_IGN, more details [here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reap_zombie_processes_using_a_sigchld_handler.html)); otherwise the child processes stick around as zombies waiting for the parent to read their exit status.

Comment: Okay I'm trying it out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @immibus and @ShadowRanger's suggestion, I modified the code as follows and it worked fine (added signal call outside my server accept while loop):

```
 signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
 ...
 while (1) {
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c); 
    if (client_sock < 0) {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        perror("fork"); 
        exit(1);
    }else if (pid == 0){ 
        close(socket_desc); 
        /* code to handle request */
        close(client_sock);

        // exit(0);
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
    }

    close(client_sock);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to fork, likely because you have hit a user or system limit on the number of processes you can create. The reason for this is that while you are having the children exit themselves properly, you are not "waiting" on them afterwards in the parent. What this means is that the process does not get cleaned up and certain resources are left allocated for it.

One way of handling this is to have the parent respond to the SIGCHLD, which is a signal the OS sends to parent to inform it of a child's termination.

Using the example from  https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html#simpleserver you add a function for the OS to call on the occurrence of the event, and then use a sys call to inform the OS of your intent to use this function for that signal.

You add

```
void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);

    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

and at some point in your main function you do

```
struct sigaction sa;

sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
}
```

The nice thing is that you can use this method to react to other signals from the OS, as well as extend it upon the death of a child.